# [django]when debug=false,MEDIA_URL returns not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, debugging, media-url

when DEBUG=TRUE,media_url is working,but DEBUG = False ,returns not working.

This is my setting file.

**setting.py**

```
DEBUG = False
...
MEDIA_URL = "/pics/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
   ....
   ....
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**home.html**

```
...
<img src="{{ post.image.url}}" ..>
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title    = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    image    = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/")
```

maybe,this setting is recommended debug-mode. 

What shuld I change this setting.

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py collectstatic`?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Comment: I would recommend to serve Media files not through the Django application, instead use a different vHost (with apache2, nginx, etc). Doing this gives you more control over the media files, and you can ensure that these files are served in a specific format (eg. text/plain or image/png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development):

> This helper function works only in debug mode and only if the given
>   prefix is local (e.g. /media/) and not a URL (e.g.
>   http://media.example.com/).

With the helper function they mention being: `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Setting up static & media files for nginx in production very simple, [DigitalOcean has a great guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#configure-nginx-to-proxy-pass-to-gunicorn). The Static part is just a couple lines:

```
    location /media/ {
        root /home/sammy/myproject;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked  ! i modify nginx setting,url.py following your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Set this code below to **"urls.py"** to show media files in **"DEBUG = False"**:

```py
# "urls.py"

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
]
```